# dictionary to mongodb insert all data in one document

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I try to import a CSV file in mongodb, but with my code, it inserts all in only one document:

```
file_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
mongo_client = MongoClient()
db = mongo_client.football

file_path2 = file_path + ".json"

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)  # loading csv file
df.to_json(file_path2)  # saving to json file
            
with open(file_path2) as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)

db.joueurs.insert_many([file_data])
```

I want to insert them in differents documents.

Comment: You can use csv module's `DictReader` to read the data as rows of dictionaries (which can be stored in a list and used with insertMany method).

Comment: You can also  import CSV or JSON using the `mongoimport` tool (this is not Python) - and has options for various data scenarios. (The question requires more information about the data in the files, so that proper tool or technique can be applied to find an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to read a CSV and load the data into a MongoDB collection. Assuming the data in the file is as follows:

```
col1,col2
a,1
b,2
```

The following Python and PyMongo code will create two documents in the collection.

```
data = []
file_name = "some.csv"

with open(file_name, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)    # using Python's csv module
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

result = collection.insert_many(data)
```

The resulting documents in the collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("626fc502c9bbf326c869f434"), "col1" : "a", " col2" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("626fc502c9bbf326c869f435"), "col1" : "b", " col2" : "2" }
```