# Insert csv data into mongo collection row by row in python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I want to insert data in the csv file into mongo collection in python. The code runs without errors but no data is inserted into mongo collection.

```
 with open("sales.csv", "r") as f:                                                   
        file=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')                                      
        header=[]                                                    
        dict_from_csv=dict(list(file)[0])                           
        header=list(dict_from_csv.keys())                                  
        print('Header: ',header)                         
        for i in file:                          
            row={}                     
            for j in header:                          
                row[j]=i[j]                               
                                      
            db.data.insert(row)
```

I don't understand why it is not inserting any data? What changes should i make to insert it rowwise into mongo collection

Comment: Here is a SO post with example code to insert csv data into MongoDB database using Pyhton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085876/dictionary-to-mongodb-insert-all-data-in-one-document/72086367#72086367

Comment: Thank you! @prasad_  IT  i used the example code and it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dictionary to mongodb insert all data in one document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72085876/dictionary-to-mongodb-insert-all-data-in-one-document)